# Tensorflow: all items in training batch have same predicted label

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to solve classic MNIST task with convolutional NN at Tensorflow.
My input is data from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/data

I am new to machine learning, so my code is basically a mix of copy-pastes from various sources + my own hacking around.

Currently my code is following: https://gist.github.com/arodiss/90ea76e5f5545af6b11e7f1dcfee01b5

Notice that currently instead of outputting accuracy I output only predicted labels (argmax of softmax of model output)

And here is what output looks like:

```
[8 6 4 2 6 8 7 6 6 7 6 6 4 7 0 6]
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
[9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]
[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
[4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
[7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7]
[4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
[3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]

( ... and so on)
```

So basically in every minibatch except the first (random) one all examples have the same label, which is clearly wrong. When instead I output probabilities themself, I get something like this:

```
[[  4.38091134e-30   1.28820540e-15   1.00000000e+00   1.73298234e-28
  7.69853474e-13   2.90028703e-19   9.43878135e-12   5.07752279e-17
  3.48896642e-33   3.62770106e-26]
[  0.00000000e+00   2.62364278e-33   3.19788233e-34   0.00000000e+00
  3.95365081e-34   1.00000000e+00   1.16309332e-11   0.00000000e+00
  5.20279699e-38   0.00000000e+00]
[  3.01065546e-22   3.79994231e-11   3.48180471e-08   1.23861001e-14
  4.11970850e-31   1.00000000e+00   4.88898765e-25   0.00000000e+00
  4.25802429e-18   0.00000000e+00]

(... and so on)
```

Any advice how to fix this particular issue?
Any advice overall? (as a newbie I probably did a lot of things in a wrong way)

**ANSWER FOUND**: I encoded my data as "channels first" but treated it as "channels last".
With convolutions this leads to specified result, ie all items in batch have same label

Answer (score 1):

MNIST is a classical example and actually part of the official tensorflow tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners).

What I think the problem here is that you did not shuffle the dataset and trained only on minibatches using the same label and you kinda learned that using batch normalization. It is also possible that your samples have the same label for every minibatch. You should give an accuracy metric to judge your program.